# How to call function that was defined in another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React I am showing a grid. In that I have kept a delete icon with a delete method. This is column layout for that grid:

```
export const ObjectEx = [
{
    name: "Test1",
    field: "Test1"
    edit: true,
    action: (cellProps) => {
       return (<div><Icon name="Delete" onClick={this.delete} /></div>)
    }

}
]
```

Here the delete action need to call in this component. The component code is as follows:

```
export default class ObjectCategory extends Component {
    //here in this class I need call delete
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    delete() {
       // delete action code
    }

    return (
       <div>Here my code will added</div>
    )
}
```

How can call that delete action method from that class to this class in React?

I tried calling this calling that delete in the component code but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it.

You can pass the function as prop to your child component.

```
const functionName = () => {} 
<ChildComponent propName={functionName}
```

Then in child conponent

```
const ChildComponent = ({propName}) => {


     // propName will be passed as a function to your component and now you can use it where ever u want.
}
```

If above method involves lot of components to pass the function, then use CONTEXTAPI and pass the use it with CONTEXT consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass that function using props to the component and use that function in that component accordingly.
import {useState} from 'react';

```
function Child({handleClick}) {
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

function handleClick() {
    console.log('Function ran in Child component');
    setCount(count + 1);
}
```

return (

### Call Child component like this

```
  <Child handleClick={handleClick} />
```

);
}